# Combining aggregated query outputs from different tables

Tags: postgresql

I would really appreciate some help with a postgreSQL issue I've been having.
I have 3 tables (category1, category2, category3) which contain several columns, one of which, is the same across all 3 tables ("Project"). I have no issues extracting the number of items per project from each of the tables individually by using this query:

```
select
a.project,
count(a.id) as "count_category1"
from category1 a
group by a.project
order by a.project asc
```

[image: please see this example]

However, I've been unable to combine the three queries into one to obtain the desired result

[image: intended result]

I've tried a wide range of queries but I cannot find a SQL statement that can achieve this. The closest I came to a 'combined' result is using LEFT JOIN which unfortunately multiplies the count values.

```
select
a.project,
count(a.id) as "count_category1",
count(b.id) as "count_category2",
count(c.id) as "count_category3"
from category1 a
left join category2 b on a.project = b.project
left join category3 c on a.project = c.project
group by a.project
order by a.project asc
```

[image: result here]

I would really appreciate any help here since I'm quite new to SQL and the solution does not seem to be easily accessible through documentation and online forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your require output look like a reporting output. Using only sql query will look bit complex. However, I have prepare the query for you, which will return exact output what you want.

```
      select case when fast2.project is null then c3.project else fast2.project 
      end,fast2.count_category1,fast2.count_category2,c3.count_category3 FROM 
    
            (SELECT case when c1.project is null then c2.project else c1.project 
            end,c1.count_category1,c2.count_category2 from
              (select
              a.project,
              count(a.id) as "count_category1"
              from category1 a
              group by a.project
              order by a.project ASC) c1
              full outer join
              (select
              a.project,
              count(a.id) as "count_category2"
              from category2 a
              group by a.project
              order by a.project ASC) c2
              on c1.project=c2.project
            ) fast2
    
    full outer join 
    (select
    a.project,
    count(a.id) as "count_category3"
    from category3 a
    group by a.project
    order by a.project ASC) c3
    on fast2.project=c3.project
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is awesome. The reason it needed to look like a reporting output is because it needs to run in a basic internal visualization tool that has minimal capabilities (unlike PowerBI, Tableau, etc.). The software itself is designed for something else and external querying is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think  `count(distinct id)` is what need.

Something like:

```sql
select
  project_id,
  count(distinct a),
  count(distinct b),
  count(distinct c)
from
  project
group by project_id;
```

Here a full running example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3566b/1/0